# asp.net multiple copies of jQuery - Visual Studio

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, libraries

Every time I spin up a new project in Visual Studio I have a collection of JavaScript files in the Scripts directory - some of which I will use. Now my projects directory is filled with identical JavaScript files, Entity Framework DLLs, etc.

Is there a way that I can keep a centralized folder and have all of the projects reference that location?  I have considered using a CDN for files like jQuery but it also helps to have the files locally in case (gasp) I am not "on the line".

Comment: You *can* do that, but IMO you're creating a potential problem for anyone else who might have to maintain your code at a later date; they will need an identical folder structure on their machine, containing the same files, without which projects might not load or compile properly. Is it such a big problem to have multiple copies of scripts or reference DLL's on one machine ? I don't believe so.

Comment: What about nuGet ?  You can have a local nuget repository for your organisation.

Comment: You could create your own static website and reference the js files from there.